# Find the set of all heptominoes

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

I have a way to represent a [heptomino](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Heptomino.html) as an undirected graph. Each square is a vertex, when two squares' vertices touch they form an edge of length 1 in the graph.

An example heptomino and its corresponding graph:

[image: An example heptomino and its corresponding graph]

My question is, how would I go about finding a set to describe all graphs of 7 vertices that make a heptomino? There are certain rules that must hold.

For instance, geometrically, the graph is composed of 1 and 2-simplexes. Also the degree of a vertex must be between 1 and 6.

I'm trying to find a way to know if a generated graph is a heptomino or not. This is a recreational investigation so if you notice any other interesting properties of the graph representation please let me know!

Comment: Note that the graph for a different heptomino, with the top bar extending to the left, would be isomorphic to the given graph

Comment: Yes that's alright, the representation is for free heptominoes. Reflections and rotations are not distinct. So in total this theoretical set should describe 108 unique graphs.

Comment: It is not only a matter of reflections: as Hagen points out, if you take the upper pointing to the left and the middle bar to the right, you get a DIFFERENT heptomino, but with the same graph.

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptomino

Comment: Oh I see. That's unfortunate. Thanks for pointing that out @HagenvonEitzen